# How do i make my text move to a new line if the text is very long

Tags: flutter

I tried putting text in a container but the text is too long for the container to contain so am looking for a way to break the text into another line ...please what should i do?

Comment: Add you current code that is making the text not go into a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Flexible widget.

Answer (score 0):

Provide container width double.infinity.